# What is process chain component in mule ESB?

Tags: mule, batch-processing

I have come across a scenario where process chain is used inside batch commit and it's size is 100 records.
What is the purpose of process chain here? Even batch is executing message in same order it gets.

```
<batch:process-records> <batch:step name="Batch_Step" > <batch:commit doc:name="Batch Commit" size="5000"> <processor-chain doc:name="PC"> <dw:transform-message metadata:id="123" doc:name="Transform Message"> <dw:set-payload>.......</dw:set-payload> </dw:transform-message> <sfdc:create-batch config-ref="SFA_NOL_MSBI" doc:name="Salesforce"> <sfdc:job-info ref="#[flowVars.jobInfo_delete]"/> <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/> </sfdc:create-batch> </processor-chain> </batch:commit></batch:step></batch:process-records>
```

Comment: The point which confused me is what is significance of process-chain inside batch commit ?

Comment: You do not put your code in a comment.  You edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

`processor-chain` is mainly used in those message processors not allowing more than one nested processor.
For example [Message Enricher](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/message-enricher) which allows only one message processor inside it and if you want multiple message processors needs to be configured `processor-chain` inside enricher enricher :-

```
<enricher source="#[your mel expression]" target="#[flowVars.myVal]">
    <processor-chain>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/mytest/test/1" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[message.payload(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </processor-chain>
</enricher>
```

Here note that, inside [Message Enricher](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/message-enricher), you can use multiple components like `http:request` and `logger` at same time which is not possible without `processor-chain`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. The point which confused me is what is significance of process-chain inside batch commit ? Here batch commit allows multiple mule components inside it.